# Questions on propositional logical proof (comma",", colon":", definition of subset)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Recently, I started to study Set theory and mathematical logics. And the goal here is making proof as rigorous as possible for each problems.

1. Definition of subset
   According to the book
   $$A\subset B\space when\space x\in A \to x \in B $$
   and
   $$p\implies q \space when \space p\to q \space is \space true$$
   Then is it safe to say below?
   $$A\subset B\space \iff (\space x\in A \implies x \in B) \space...(1) $$
   1-1. I tried to solve the problem below
   $$prove, A \subset B \iff A\cap B=A$$
   based on $(1)$
   $$A\subset B \iff (x \in A \implies x \in B)\ ...(2)$$
   $$\iff (x\in A^c) \lor(x\in B)\ ...(3)$$
   $$\iff x\in A^c \cup B \ ...(4)$$??
   It's clear that I reached insanity here. What was the problem? $(1)$or  $(2) to (3)$?

$$\ $$

2.comma and colon's representation on logical symbol

based on the textbook, the definition of intersection and union of set can be written as such
$$\cap _{i\in I}A_i=\{x: \forall i \in I, x\in A_i\}, \cup _{i\in I}A_i=\{x: \exists \in I, x\in A_i\}...(5)$$

And the definition of product set is
$$A\times B = \{(a,b): a\in A, b\in B\}$$

While some text book writes the same definition as
$$A\times B = \{(a,b): a\in A\land b\in B\}$$

Thus I thought there is equivalency between $,$ and $\land$. Nonetheless I found it becomes problematic when I regard those two as equivalent for definition $(5)$. (it deduced result that doesn't make sense)

2-1. One of the problem says
$$Negate \ ``\forall e \gt0, \exists N : n\ge N \to \frac{1}{n}\lt e"$$

Me and my boys who study together came up with the different answer.

(i) leave the 'condition', negate the 'proposition'.  "$ \forall e \gt0$" is condition and "$\exists N : n\ge N \to \frac{1}{n}\lt e$"is proposition thus  $$(\forall e \gt0),\lnot (\exists N : n\ge N \to \frac{1}{n}\lt e)$$
$$\iff (\forall e \gt0), (\not\exists N : n\ge N \to \frac{1}{n}\lt e)$$
$$\iff (\forall e \gt0), (\forall N : n\ge N \to \frac{1}{n}\ge e)$$

(ii) Negate all
$$\exists e\gt0, \forall N: \lnot (n\ge N \to \frac{1}{n}\lt e)$$
$$\iff \exists e\gt0, \forall N: (n\ge N) \land \lnot (\frac{1}{n}\lt e)$$
$$\iff \exists e\gt0, \forall N:  (\frac{1}{n}\lt e\to  n\ge N)$$
Which I believe the problem arise from the fact that no one doesn't know how to handle ',' and ':' properly.

Summarize based on our experience,  ',' changes it's meaning depends on the context(for example and, such that, ...)and it's not even a mathematical symbol.

Is there any kinds of rule how to handle ',' and ':' in logical operation? or is there way to write definition solely upon mathematical symbol?

Comment: Too many questions at once … please separate these into separate posts. Thanks!

Comment: [Ask one question per post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#33671)

Comment: 1. Yes but with the universal quantifier $\forall x$

Comment: 2. Yes, sometimes the colon is used as "and".

Comment: In the big formula in (i) there is no need to use colon between quantifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sympathetic to your confusion about the uses of *comma*, *colon* and $\wedge$. Mathematicians are pretty liberal about the uses of the former two.

In the case of $\forall e>0, \exists N: n \ge N \rightarrow \frac{1}{n}<e $, the *comma* is used as a terminator to a prepositional phrase, as though the author wrote "for each *e*, there is *N* such that...

In the case of the definition of the product set, the *comma* is used as a list separator, which in natural language, is equivalent to the $\wedge$ operator. One simply has to get used to these conventions.

Now, to address your proof: Your conclusion is correct, but unfortunately leading in the wrong direction. Maybe you could try starting from the other direction with the definition of $A \cap B$ instead.